# Using gorillamux in gcp cloud function

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gorilla

I am new to `Go` and new to `GCP` so i may not be able to put all details. But will try to share what i have.

I have setup a small microservice using docker. The docker-compose file runs my `main` method which register http handler via `gorrillamux` ... it is working as expected. here is sample code

```golang
func main() {
    r := gorrilamux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/stores/orders/{orderID}/status", handler).Methods("GET")
    http.Handle("/", r)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("------ in handler!!!")
}
```

With this code, I am able to call my service after doing `docker-compose -up`. The thing which i am confused at that how would i use this gorrilla mux to route my calls in goocle cloud function?

Based on my understanding, for GCP CF, I would tell what method is the entry point i.e.,

```sh
gcloud functions deploy service-name <removing_other_details> --entry-point handler
```

This `handler` would call whenever each request is received, it wouldn't be `ListenandServce`. So how can i use `gorillamux` to do so?

What i eventually want to do is extract path variables from incoming request. One approach is to use string manipulation and just get path variable from `request` object. But this could be error prone. So i thought if i can use gorilla mux to handle such things.

Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Functions is used to execute Single Purpose functions based on triggers like HTTP or another GCP server to server triggers. Your go service looks more like an HTTP server than a single function.

If you want to establish a microservice architecture with Cloud Functions what you are going to do is create a bunch of different functions mainly triggered by HTTP (each one will have a different HTTP address assigned automatically) and then call them from your application without needing any external HTTP router.

If you want to have a distributed microservice (with every single service sharing the same URL but with a different endpoint within the URL) You want to take a look into [Appengine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) where you can deploy your server. You can use [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/building-app) tutorial to get started with Google Appengine

Comment: thats what i thought (i had more java/python + aws experience) just wanted to confirm. One last question, is there a preferred library to extract path parameters from `request` object ? the only option i could think of is doing string split on `/` but just wanted to make sure i am not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I think it's okay to use string split or regex rather than any library, especially if you use bucket as a trigger. Or if you want to use one, try this: https://github.com/arduino/go-paths-helper

Answer (score 0):

In addition of PoWar answer, I propose you to use Cloud Run instead of App Engine. Cloud Run works on the same underlying infrastructure as Cloud Functions and a lot of feature are similar.

In addition, Cloud Run uses containers which are one of the top current best practices to package the applications. You can use a standard `Dockerfile` like this one in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#go_1), and then build with docker. Or Cloud Build if you haven't docker installed

```
gcloud builds submit -t gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/containerName
```

Or you can even an alpha feature if you don't want to write or customize your `Dockerfile`, this is based on buildpack

```
gcloud alpha builds submit --pack=image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/containerName
```

And then deploy your image on Cloud Run

```
gcloud run deploy --image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/containerName --platform=managed --region=yourRegion myService
```